# Using QtWebKit with Qt5 beta

Tags: qt, webkit, qml, qtwebkit

I have installed the beta version of Qt5 on a Mac and am trying to add a Web View component to another qml type.  However my program is failing with the error: `module "QtWebKit" is not installed`.

I've added the following to my .pro file:

> QT += webkit

and a suitable include statement to my .qml file:

> include QtQuick 2.0
>   include QtWebKit 3.0

Could anyone suggest what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

First, I suggest upgrading to Qt 5 release version. Also note that if you want to use WebKit in your .pro file you need include  `QT += webkit webkitwidgets` starting in Qt 5.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Lion (10.7) or newer version of Mac OS? As per the [Qt5 beta known issues list](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt500beta1KnownIssues), it's a requirement for Webkit. Also note that it's an [Addon](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Add-ons-Modules) and not an Essential package, so it might not come by default in the installation package as it's optional.

Comment: I'm using Mountain Lion (10.8).  Is there a standardised way of installing the addons that you know of?